Modify polygons imported from a MyMaps KML files

I made a map on MyMaps, I managed to import it to QGIS but I can't select the polygons to modify them. How can I do this?

You can use the Select Features tool to select them by clicking. First, make sure the correct layer is selected in the Layers palette on the left. Then, choose the Select Feature(s) tool either by using the icon in the toolbar, or using Edit > Select > Select Feature(s) in the menu bar. Finally, click anywhere within the feature.
Learn more in the QGIS documentation.
